# Get post thumbnail to display favorites

Tags: post-thumbnails

I use this line:

```
echo (the_user_favorites_list($user_id = um_profile_id(), $site_id = null, $include_links = true, $filters = null, $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id()));
```

to display a user's favorites but only the link to the post is displayed.
I thought:

```
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id()
```

would also display the thumbnail picture but it's not the case.
How should I modify this to have:

```
*Post1 title link*
*Thumbnail1* 

*Post2 title link*
*Thumbnail2*
```

Here is the code:

```
function get_user_favorites_list($user_id = null, $site_id = null, $include_links = false, $filters = null, $include_button = false)
{
    global $blog_id;
    $site_id = ( is_multisite() && is_null($site_id) ) ? $blog_id : $site_id;
    if ( !is_multisite() ) $site_id = 1;
    $favorites = new UserFavorites($user_id, $site_id, $include_links, $filters);
    return $favorites->getFavoritesList($include_button);
}

function the_user_favorites_list($user_id = null, $site_id = null, $include_links = false, $filters = null, $include_button = false)
{
    echo get_user_favorites_list($user_id, $site_id, $include_links, $filters, $include_button);
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: the_user_favorites_list is not a core function, so without seeing the code behind that function it's impossible to say how to fix it.

Comment: @vancoder I edited the code, thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_post_thumbnail_id()` only returns the ID of the thumbnail.
To get the actual thumbnail you could instead use [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/)

You can also get the image using it´s ID, but that requires `wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' )`